# Error when I run the Visual studio run task in CI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .net application and I am getting below error while running Visual studio task in CI pipeline.

##[error]No agent found in pool TEST APP which satisfies the following demand: visualstudio. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pool does not contain build agents with Visual Studio. You can check your polls and agents on the administration page: [Agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser).

You have to install and register a build agent on a server or virtual machine with visual studio.
Additionally, if your project on Azure DevOps Services, you can use [MS Hosted build agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Update your yaml to:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
```

or if you use classic build, update here:

[image]